# Convert int field in date field (mysql)

Tags: mysql, date, casting

I must change a table that in past collected years of born, but now must collect entire date.

I have a field called "born" that is a INT, but when i've tried to simply convert it into a date field in a copy table, i lost all "born" data (i've just 0000-00-00 dates).

Is there a way to perform this casting without lost information?

eg. if i have a int field like "2011" it must be like "01-01-2011" in date format.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create another date field, let's say born2.
2. Update it with `update yourtable set born2=concat(born,'-01-01')`
3. Remove the original born column (obviously, check for errors befor that)
4. Rename born2 to born